# How to convert MySqli Loop Code Laravel controller

Tags: laravel-5, mysqli, eloquent

I want to work on a while loop in a foreach loop but I can't convert it to Laravel controller system. Please help.

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i) 
{
echo $i = strtolower($i); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `list` Where name like '$i%' Limit 30";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo"<hr><h3>Name Starting with ".strtoupper($i)."</h3>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo "<li><a href=\"name/".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</a></li>";
}
echo "<li><a href=\"name/".$i."\">More</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
}
```

The code in Laravel that I have is

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i) 
{
    $list = DB::table('list')->where('name', 'LIKE', $i.'%')->limit(30)->get();            
    return view('pages.all', ['list' => $list]);            
}
```

This code only gives data for names starting with alphabet "a" but won't proceed with the rest of the characters.

Comment: return statement used in your `foreach` loop !

Answer (score 0):

Store it on the array based on your search.

```
$list = array();
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i) {
    $list[$i] = DB::table('list')->where('name', 'LIKE', $i.'%')->limit(30)->get();            
}
return view('pages.all', ['list' => $list]);
```

Customize your view, to showing the list against each character (a-z).

*[Edit]*

View file can be changed like below,

```
@foreach ($list as $keyI => $moredata)
    <hr>
    <h3>Author's Name Starting with "{{strtoupper($keyI)}}"</h3>
    <ul class="tags-list">
        @foreach ($moredata as $data)
            <li><a href="/{{$data->slug}}">{{$data->name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks @Tamilvanan N that worked but the problem is how can also get the value of $i
I also need to show it in the loop.
`
  @foreach ($list as $moredata)
    <hr>
    <h3>Author's Name Starting with "{{strtoupper($i)}}"</h3>
    <ul class="tags-list">
    @foreach ($moredata as $data)
    <li><a href="/{{$data->slug}}">{{$data->name}}</a></li>
    @endforeach 
    </ul>       
    @endforeach    
`
but it either shows a or z.

Comment: Check the updated answer. `$i` has to be taken from foreach-key.